# Como retonar 2 consultas desde un sp usando entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo un problema para tratar de retornar informacion desde un sp, lo que pasa que el sp retorna 2 consultas, el total de filas de la consulta y otra con toda la información, estoy usando entity framework y dbcontext, como puedo retonar las 2 consultas con Entity Framework? ya que actualmente solo puedo traer lo que viene siendo la 1ra consulta y no la 2da, adjunto codigo

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter FkSucursal = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@fkSucursal", SqlDbType.Int);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter FkAlmacen= new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@fkAlmacen", SqlDbType.Int);

Fk.Sucursal.Value = fkSucursal;
FkAlmacen.Value = fkAlmacen;

list = await _applicationDbContext.Productos.FromSqlRaw("EXEC spGetProductos @fkSucursal, @fkAlmacen", FkSucursal, FkAlmacen).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets

Comment: eso estuve viendo pero como lo adaptaria con fromsqlraw, porque es una forma diferente

Comment: No utilizando FromSqlRaw sino como lo dice en el artículo

Comment: no eso conllevaría a cambiar toda mi estructura?

Comment: ¿Qué estructura? Yo sólo veo 4 líneas de código que no hacen lo que necesitas

Comment: seria lo que es mi DBContext